# Should I just hide the AdMob adview or remove it completely?

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-view

As a lot free apps, my own also sports AdMob ads where the premium version removes them. The premium version will be an unlocker key. Right now, when this key is detected and validated in the free version, I just hide the `AdView` with `setVisibility(View.GONE)` and the user never sees it.

I'm wondering if, in this specific scenario, it would be best to remove the view from the layout instead of just hiding it. I mean, the `AdView` will **NEVER** be shown to the user, ever.

Comment: I've never used this but if the ads are fetched over the network connection then I think you should remove them, so it doesn't consume anyone's data allowance unnecessarily even if he's paid for the app.

Comment: @Dreen I'm not sure but I *think* if the view is gone, it won't fetch for new ads, that's why I'm not sure if I it's OK to just hide or if I should remove it.

Comment: Would you be able to create your own ad and restrict it to appear on your test device only? Then you could be sure by looking through stats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it's best practice to remove the AdView.

I believe the AdMob SDK checks the visibility of the AdView and won't make another request if the AdView is not visible. However, you're still unnecessarily calling to the AdMob SDK code, and if a bug gets introduced in the SDK or on some Android device, you don't want to be unnecessarily hitting the network.

You should also check for premium status prior to creating the AdView, so the AdView never gets created again once the user made the purchase.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. For the record though, I'm going to use a `ViewStub` and instead of removing the view from the layout I inflate the ad layout if it's not the premium version.